Generate include files for Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK with cppwinrt in CMake library project
For an attempt to provide activation feature for a Flutter plugin I try to integrate Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK which is needed to get the required extensions.
Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary and Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT are included with success and sdk include files from CppWinRT are generated.
I'm very new with all this. Am I missing something?
Here's a view of my current CMakeLists.txt to generate include files.
set(CPPWINRT ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/packages/Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT.${CPPWINRT_VERSION}/bin/cppwinrt.exe)
execute_process(COMMAND
    ${CPPWINRT} -input ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK.${WASDK_VERSION}/ -output include
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
    RESULT_VARIABLE ret)
if (NOT ret EQUAL 0)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Failed to run cppwinrt.exe to generate WindowsAppSDK include files.")
endif()

This does not generate any file and I don't get any error either. cppwinrt.exe is supposed to scan recursively the given folder.
If I try to target Microsoft.Windows.AppLifecycle.winmd, I get the following error:
cppwinrt : error Type 'Windows.Foundation.IAsyncAction' could not be found

The Windows App SDK is incredibly hard to consume using anything but Visual Studio/MSBuild. It is apparently so difficult or impractical that even Microsoft gave up on the idea of delivering Rust bindings. If you still want to follow that path, the best you can do is go with a standard C++ WAS template, run it through the MSBuild Binary and Structured Log Viewer, and extrapolate what to pass to the individual tools as input. Doable, but not a whole lot of fun.
